# Tomcat specific web.xml settings

Tags: tomcat

Is there a way to configure specific settings for my web application that will only be applied and acted upon when running under Tomcat?

We use Tomcat 6.0.29 as a development environment under Eclipse Helios as it's quick and easy for developers to use, but would then typically use a Java EE 6 container (Weblogic, Websphere, JBoss etc) for Production environments.

The specific issue I have is that for JAX-WS services running under Tomcat (a non Java EE server) I need to add a listener to web.xml (com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener) and a servlet reference for each Web Services class I write. If using a true Java EE 6 container I don't have to do this as it auto-deploys the web services at EAR deployment time based on their @WebService annotations.

For other app servers there are files such as jboss-web.xml, geronimo-web.xml and weblogic.xml that I can put under WEB-INF, but does a similar thing exist for Tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Solutions

1. Use a custom listener which will detect you are running tomcat and if you are running tomcat - then instantiate the WSServletContextListener and call its init method.
2. Edit CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml and add the listener - But this will be used for ALL webapps on that instance

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It still doesn't address the individual servlet references which need to be created in addition to the listener though. The update to the main web.xml might be the better option, though not ideal. Thanks